# mysql data retrieving error with IF condition in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the below mysql query,

```
$userlist_sql = "SELECT id,role,to_role,type,points,company_code,total_pairs,invoice_no,invoice_date,division,created_at, 
IF( role = '6', (select name from dealers where dealers.id=loyality_points_history.user_id and dealers.state='{$state_code}'), (select name from sub_dealers where sub_dealers.id=loyality_points_history.user_id and sub_dealers.state='{$state_code}' )) AS from_name,
IF( role = '6', (select customer_id from dealers where dealers.id=loyality_points_history.user_id and dealers.state='{$state_code}'), (select customer_id from sub_dealers where sub_dealers.id=loyality_points_history.user_id and sub_dealers.state='{$state_code}' )) AS from_userID,
IF( role = '6', (select city from dealers where dealers.id=loyality_points_history.user_id and dealers.state='{$state_code}'), (select city from sub_dealers where sub_dealers.id=loyality_points_history.user_id and sub_dealers.state='{$state_code}' )) AS from_city,
FROM loyality_points_history  where from_userID != null";
```

If from_userID is empty, don't want to fetch the corresponding data from loyality_points_history table. By using the above query getting error "Unknown column from_userID". but I want to check  from_userID is empty or not.

Comment: Have you tried it using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`? That will probably solve your problem.

Comment: you can not use an alias in where clause, as @jeroen had mentioned you will need to use HAVING instead

Comment: Yes, Issue fixed by using HAVING. Thank you